# Can Python Bottle Catch a Second 404 in a 404 Catch?

Tags: python, bottle

I've successfully implemented 404 handling in my Python Bottle application - as below - and my application is required show a static file upon hitting a 404.

But what if that file isn't there and it itself produces a 404?

Right now I get an application error in this case, but is there a way to generate a custom 404 if the 404 catching function throws a 404?  Thanks!

```
from bottle import Bottle, error

"""App Instantiation"""
app = application = Bottle()

@app.error(404)
def error404(error):
    return static_file(filepath, root=domain_root)
```

Comment: er... can't you just check if the file exists before opening it?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error in the handler, then handle it when the error is raised:

```
from bottle import Bottle, error

"""App Instantiation"""
app = application = Bottle()

@app.error(404)
def error404(error):
    value=None
    try:
        value=static_file(filepath, root=domain_root)
    except <error_being_raised>:
        #generate dynamic 404 and assign it to value then return, or return
        #it straight from here
    if value != None:
        return value
```

As far as bottle is concerned, they do not give you a clean way to do this, so you have to write it yourself.